# Postgresql + POSTGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to deploy PostgreSQL + PostGIS for my ruby app. I follow [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/ansell/4e2843345e6c55c794c80eda3dff8968), but when I'm typing: `CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS` the terminal returns,

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE : undefined command
```

**my setup:**

- POSTGRESQL 10.4
- Ruby 2.4.3
- Rails 5.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you executing `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`? This command has to be executed in the database via a PostgreSQL client, such as [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html) or [`pgAdmin`](https://www.pgadmin.org/). What you're getting is an error message from your console, which does not know this command.

Try this from your console:

```
psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis"
```

Check the psql documentation for more details on how to connect to the database.